# Laravel middleware api always return null even with the correct token

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-5, postman

I just use the default api that laravel provided with a little change when i make the project which is

```
    Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return User::all();
});
```

I already make api_token in user table and fill it with some token
When i use postman the api works
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDU8l.png)

But when i write the request code in the controller it always return null

```
$token = 'abcde';
$request = Request::create('/api/user', 'GET', [
'Accept' => 'application/json',
'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
]);
$response = json_decode(Route::dispatch($request)->getContent());
dd($response);
```

The api works if i dont use middleware('auth:api')
Any suggestion?

EDIT
I tried to use Guzzle and get this error
[Guzzle Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q8qI.png)

Comment: what auth you are using passport jwt

Comment: It's the default laravel auth:api. But i use jwt just to generate the random token when the user register an account.

Comment: then use jwt default one will not work like this  u can read this https://medium.com/@danielalvidrez/how-to-use-laravels-built-in-token-auth-6b6f6c26d059

Comment: But it still return null even if i use a hardcoded token like the one in the postman picture above.

Comment: you can't set token like that

Comment: Then how? I already make a new project for this question and follow the laravel documentation and make a 60 char random string and add it to api_token everytime the user register. But still it returns null when i call for the api through the code. No jwt this time

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Guzzle`

```php
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$token = 'abcde';
$request = $client->request('api/user', 'GET', [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
        ]);
$response = $request->getBody()->getContents();
$response = json_decode($request,true);
dd($response);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now i got cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: GET (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html). Is there any guzzle setting that i need to do ?

Comment: Still the same cURL error 6 pop up. For your info i use php artisan serve to make a local development server.

Comment: no don't use php artisan serve use localhost only agian check updated code

Comment: But how to run laravel without php artisan serve?

Comment: I tried to run it using xampp localhost but still the error 6 popped up

Comment: php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear try this

Comment: Now i got json response message:unauthenticated even with the right token